# document.execCommand - Close <pre> block

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, pre, execcommand

I try to create a `<pre>` block in a contenteditable area by using `document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'&zwnj;<pre><div>&zwnj;');` but my problem is that I can't find how to close it properly.

At this point, I only found a partial solution who let two unwanted empty lines inside the `<pre>` block and one outside.

**HTML:**

```
<p><button type="button" id="on">OPEN PRE BLOCK</button><button type="button" id="off">CLOSE PRE BLOCK</button></p>
<div id="edit-area" contenteditable="true" class="classy">
    <h1>This is heading</h1>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis, lacinia quis facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu. Sed arcu lectus auctor vitae, consectetuer et venenatis eget velit. Sed augue orci, lacinia eu tincidunt et eleifend nec lacus. Donec ultricies nisl ut felis, suspendisse potenti.</div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div>Red color is for div blocs</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
pre {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: consolas,monaco,"Andale Mono",monospace;

    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    //white-space: pre;
}

div:not(.classy) {
  color: red;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#on').click(function() {
  document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'&zwnj;<pre><div>&zwnj;');
});

$('#off').click(function() {
  document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<br>\u200C");
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<br>\u200C");
});
```

See by yourself:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnz30451/33/)

Thanks, Bob

PS: This is my first post so if I'm not doing something good, tell me ;)

And Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code you're using into your question, formatted as code.  There's no </pre> in the linked jsfiddle..

Comment: Also, why are you using `&zwnj` it's much better to use CSS to handle your layout.

Comment: It's seems that it doesn't go into the pre block without it

Comment: And the </pre> is automatically put at the end, because of the contenteditable area. The problem is that I can't find how to close it, except by using tips like <br> blocks

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know how, can you show me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

why you not use `document.execCommand FormatBlock` for create `<pre>`

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnz30451/36/)**